# FOC point vs Stationary point in local optimization

Tags: nonconvex-programming, convexity, optimality-conditions

In [this SIAM Review paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/110839072?casa_token=vUpJFGKvqjcAAAAA:qI5sdpK3YYgx47o_3cytwteA-Ncr-Qctvn9mAdMBiifGQHu2Hy2BdXp-5J1p71lB9cvJHRMOhwT9) the authors are giving the following necessary condition for a point being a local maximum of a convex function:

> Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be convex. If $x$ is a local maximum of $F$ over the nonempty compact set $C$, then
> \begin{align}\tag{FOC}
> \langle v - x, F'(x)\rangle \leq 0 \quad \forall v \in C.
> \end{align}

Moreover, the authors state that if $F$ is continuously differentiable, then any $x$ satisfying the above first-order condition will be referred to as a *stationary point*, and otherwise *a point that satisfies the first-order condition*.

What I do not understand is, what changes when a point is called a stationary point? It is still not guaranteed to be a local max, right? So what really changes when a point that satisfies the first-order conditions becomes a stationary point? What additional benefits do we get? (I am assuming this will be relevant when we analyze the convergence of the Frank-Wolfe algorithm or whatever we are using to find a local maximum, but I don't understand what changes with a point being *stationary*.)

Comment: The premise here looks a little shaky. The quote says $C$ is nonempty and compact, but is it assumed to be convex? Also, the quote starts with $F$ being convex but then refers to $F'$ (presumably the gradient of $F$). Convex functions are not automatically differentiable. Is there an explicit assumption that $F'$ exists?